# React-native getCurrentPosition method hanging forever on Android

Tags: android, react-native

I've got the following setup:

```
global.navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
  ({ coords: { longitude, latitude } }) => {
    await parseToBackend({ longitude, latitude });
  },
  async () => {
     await parseToBackend(false);
  },
);
```

This works perfectly fine on IOS (even when the location services are disabled), however when running this on Android (with location services disabled), it will hang forever and never timeout or error. I've tried adding the 3rd argument:

```
{enableHighAccuracy: true, timeout: 20000, maximumAge: 10000}
```

But this still doesn't fix the timeout issue. This happens on multiple different Android devices.

Is there a way around this? I'm guessing I'll just have to setup my own timeout function? Unless someone else has had this issue & has a better workaround.

Comment: There is a [package](https://github.com/webyonet/react-native-android-location-services-dialog-box) to detect if location service is on or not. I have never used it but you can take a look.